# How to check if this is a monotonic series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

The series is: $$a_n = \frac{((n-1)!)^2}{(2n-1)!}$$

How can I compare $a_n$ to $a_{n+1}$, I have an issue with the term in the denominator, how to deal with it?

Edit: I got banned because of low quality questions like this, but then answer is below, so how am I supposed to improve my questions to be able to ask questions again? I see that here you can just divide $a_{n+1}$ by $a_n$ and continue as in the answer below. Is this enough to improve this question?

Comment: You could compute $a_{n+1}-a_n$ and evaluate its sign.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio The denominator seems problematic to me, how to deal with it?

Comment: Same way you deal with the numerator, I guess.

Comment: OR $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ then compare by $1$

Comment: If you would be ashamed to copy the answer below, which I easily understand, the most natural way to improve your initial post would be to explain with more details your previous attempt(s) and how you had "an issue with the term in the denominator".

Answer (score 1):

There are many possible ways to compare $a_n$ to $a_{n+1}$, but when there are many exponentiations and factorials, there is a hint that your numbers are of multiplicative nature, hence the most natural thing to compute is the quotient $a_{n+1}/a_n$. We have :
\begin{align*}
\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} &= a_{n+1} \cdot \frac{1}{a_n}\\
&= \frac{(n!)^2}{(2n+1)!} \cdot \frac{(2n-1)!}{((n-1)!)^2}\\
&= \left(\frac{n!}{(n-1)!}\right)^2 \cdot \frac{(2n-1)!}{(2n+1)!}\\
&= n^2 \cdot \frac{1}{2n(2n+1)}\\
&= \frac{n}{2(2n+1)}.
\end{align*}

To study the monotonicity of $a_n$, we have to see if this quotient is always $< 1$, always $> 1$ or something else. Here, you can show that it is always $< 1$, since $n < 4n + 2$ for all non-negative integers $n$. We conclude that $(a_n)$ is strictly decreasing.

Comment: This question goes against [our quality standard policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards). Instead of posting an answer, you should encourage the person who posted the question to improve it.